# testing : how to wait for a page reload?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Angular 15
karma - jasmine

I am on a page, following a click on a button I go to another page (which contains TD tags)
in my tests i click the button but i don't feel the page changes

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
...
       ],
      imports: [

        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes),
...
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: HttpClient, useValue: httpClientSpy },
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ReferentielBuPilotageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    await fixture.whenStable();
  });

  it('--------', fakeAsync( () => {

    // click to change page
    const buttonShow: HTMLInputElement = document.querySelector('.bg-action');
    buttonShow.click();

    tick();

    // another page

    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        const tds2: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> = document.querySelectorAll('td');
    // tds2  is empty
    // he must have td's if he changed the page
```

I have the impression that the tick does not detect the page change

Answer (score 0):

The `tick` and the `fixture.detectChanges` should be enough but your component (`ReferentielBuPilotageComponent`) may not be enough. It most likely only has a button that navigates but it does not have a `router-outlet`.

You most likely need a test component that has the router outlet.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-comp',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
class TestComponent {}

// Add the TestComponent to your declarations in TestBed.configureTestingModule({
declarations: [..., TestComponent, ...],
...
// Make TestComponent
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();
router.navigate(/* Navigate to ReferentielBuPilotageComponent */);
await fixture.whenStable();
```

Since now we have a `<router-outlet>`, navigation should work and components that should be rendered for the route will render.